# One way bridge between interfaces

Tags: linux, networking

I'm currently trying to set up my server to be based on containers to limit RAM and CPU usage for all programs. My problem is, that I would like to have all applications in different containers listen to the same IP on different ports, but keep the flexibility and have other containers with special IPs and have full access on those. The other IPs are on aliases of eth0 (eth0:0, eth0:1 and so on).

```
+----+ +----+ +----+
|IP 1| |IP 1| |IP 2| IP
|WEB | | TS | |GAME| Application
| 80 | |9987| |ALL | Port(s)
+----+ +----+ +----+
  |     |      |
  +-----+------+
        |
     +------+
     |SERVER|
     +--+---+ 
        |
    +---+----+
    |Internet|
    +--------+
```

I searched a lot but have not been able to find anything that helps me. I am sorry when this is a duplicate, I just can't find anything... Maybe that is because I searched for the wrong keywords, or because it is impossible... Anyway, thank you for reading!

Comment: well, since you want to use multiple hosts on one IP using differant ports, you are looking for Port Address Translation (PAT) to Network Address Translation (NAT). So your best bet is to put a NAT router between the containers and the server, and forward ports from the containers to  the server. your containers would exist on their own internal IP network, but would expose to the external network a single IP with ports that translate to ports on the specific containers. Since you are talking about containers, I'm guessing the router would be virtual, but I don't know what tech you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The technology you're looking for is called Destination NAT. On a linux system, this can be done with the help of iptables.

As your question is not giving any details about the container technology you're planning to use, it depends on how these technology will connect to the local network and the host system itself - usually using a bridge interface and virtual network interfaces for the containers.

In that case, you might take a look here:
http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.2

> Change destination addresses to 5.6.7.8
>
> > iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 5.6.7.8
>
> Change destination addresses to 5.6.7.8, 5.6.7.9 or 5.6.7.10
>
> > iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 5.6.7.8-5.6.7.10
>
> Change destination addresses of web traffic to 5.6.7.8, port 8080
>
> > iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 5.6.7.8:8080

You could then have some iptables DNAT rules on your host server, that will rewrite the incoming packets on certain ports or for certain IP addresses to targets on your bridged, virtual network.

However, you would also have to set up some Source NAT rules, so that traffic from those containers is also changed to match the IP addresses that those containers should have to the outside world.